# Unreal Engine 5 docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, unreal-engine5

I'm trying to build docker image for my pixel streaming project following this tutorial
[OKE QuickStart](https://github.com/oracle-quickstart/oke-unreal-pixel-streaming/blob/main/src/unreal/README.md)

here is my dockerfile

```
# Perform the build in an Unreal Engine container image that includes the Engine Tools and Pixel Streaming for Linux
FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM:-linux/amd64} ghcr.io/epicgames/unreal-engine:dev-5.1 AS builder

# Copy UE4 project (assumes `.uproject` in this directory)
COPY --chown=ue4:ue4 . /tmp/project
WORKDIR /tmp/project


RUN /home/ue4/UnrealEngine/Engine/Build/BatchFiles/RunUAT.sh BuildCookRun \
    -clientconfig=Development -serverconfig=Development \
    -project=/tmp/project/PixelStreamingDemo.uproject \
    -utf8output -nodebuginfo -allmaps -noP4 -cook -build -stage -prereqs -pak -archive \
    -archivedirectory=/tmp/project/dist \
    -platform=Linux \
    -Target=PixelStreamingDemo -nocompile -nocompileeditor


# Copy the packaged files into a container image that includes CUDA but doesn't include any Unreal Engine components
FROM --platform=${BUILDPLATFORM:-linux/amd64} ghcr.io/epicgames/unreal-engine:runtime-pixel-streaming
WORKDIR /tmp/project
COPY --from=builder --chown=ue4:ue4 /tmp/project/dist/LinuxNoEditor ./

# Establish ENV
ENV RES_X=1920 \
    RES_Y=1080 \
    SIGNAL_URL=ws://127.0.0.1:8888

# Start pixel streaming
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "./PixelStreamingDemo.sh -PixelStreamingURL=${SIGNAL_URL} -RenderOffscreen -Unattended -ForceRes -ResX=${RES_X} -ResY=${RES_Y} -AllowPixelStreamingCommands ${EXTRA_ARGS}" ]
```

i all goes fine until I get
`Step 7/9 : COPY --from=builder --chown=ue4:ue4 /tmp/project/dist/LinuxNoEditor ./ COPY failed: stat tmp/project/dist/LinuxNoEditor: file does not exist`

I'm not clear on how to adapt this path

Answer (score 1):

Might be too late but, Epic now calls the folder "Linux" instead of "LinuxNoEditor".  Maybe try it like this?

```
COPY --from=builder --chown=ue4:ue4 /tmp/project/dist/Linux ./
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).